# How to track dirtychange event on form

Tags: extjs

I've got the form.

I track `dirtychange` event with:

```
init: function() {
    this.control({
        'form': {
            dirtychange: function(form) {
                alert('change');      
            }
        }
    });
}
```

But when I'm loading a record through `loadRecord()` method into the form I got `chage` alert while loading record.

How to start tracking `dirtychange` event ONLY after record was loaded?

Comment: What version of ExtJS is used?

Comment: I used 3rd version of ExtJS